# Have you met Judy yet? (about "yet")

Tags: present-perfect

As I understand, in general "yet" in questions is like "already" in statements. But is it possible that this example has a different meaning? One person says that this "yet" can be translated like "still not": "You haven't still met Judy, have you?". Is it correct? I'm afraid, I can't find such rule in my grammar book.

> Have you met Judy yet?

P.S. If that person is right, could you explain me how to distinguish "yet" meanings in questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both **yet** and **still** can be used in questions to convey the same meaning, where still generally carries a stronger sense of expectation. To take some examples:

**Have you met Judy yet?** is a neutral question. It does not imply that you should have met her or that you should meet her, although with more context these implications might arise.

**Haven't you met Judy yet?** carries a sense of surprise and the implication that you ought to if you haven't.

**Have you still not met Judy?** implies more strongly that you should have or ought too.

In the same way, you can use either **yet** or **still** to ask a question such as:

**Haven't you finished yet?** which implies that you should have.

**Have you still not finished?** is an even stronger way of asking the question and has a hint of irritation.

So the choice really depends on what nuances you wish to convey.